# Can i teach Arduino Uno with AI ? so it will work for me as robot

Tags: arduino, artificial-intelligence, robot

Before to dig into all things of AI , i have simple question , is it possible to teach "Arduino Uno" With Ai ? i just want to create a small brain or device that collects lots of data from server , it will filter data in any way and this particular data will imp . like i am giving command to  "Arduino Uno" call it a brain , it will search related data from Google , Bing  or Yahoo. it has complete data of anything that brain will collect understand it and act like it . for example: if brain has arm then if he receives command for to "make coffee"  then he will be search all things to require to make coffee , collects data and then ready to make coffee , then this brain with arm enters in kitchen , and it will make a coffee.

I am curious about all things. will be happy if i get reply from any one .

Thanks.

Comment: why limit yourself to Arduino Uno? there are cheaper solutions with much more performance.

Comment: can you add something more.

Comment: Where did you see this being possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

This is not possible with todays technology. Maybe you can do it if you're a super genius and invest several years of work.

The same answer holds if you replace "Arduino Uno" with any other computing device.

Comment: Thanks for reply , no matter it is possible or not , I can try for some days will look in to this surely i will get some thing from which i will find any way to dig into this or i have to close the door of my imagination for this brain development .

Answer (score 1):

Well, It could work with the Arduino 101 as it has a neural network library. It is two times faster than the Arduino Uno. The only downside is that you lose the 5v support and you can only use 3.3v shields, even though it protection against 5v shields.